# Automate monitoring of Intel Matrix / Rapid Storage Technology RAID arrays

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, intel

I need to monitor the array status of the Intel integrated RAID controllers (e.g. ICH7R, ICH9R, ICH10R) on multiple servers. Intel suggests using "Intel Matrix Storage Manager" or "Intel Rapid Storage Technology", but the programs do not provide way to automate or centralize the process of monitoring.

For some unspecified reason, I cannot parse the Windows event logs.

The "raidcfg32" and "CmdTool2" commands are not working correctly on my hardware (ESB2, 631xESB/632xESB).

What utility, API, WMI classes, or other method could I use to monitor my RAID arrays?

Answer (score 2):

They should - if they are worth a cent and not total crap - not only have logs, but also push events out to the WINDOWS EVENT LOG. Depending on your windows version you could have that provide alerts automatically.

I use adaptec here, and their program allows event log propagation AS WELL as sending out emails on issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Intel program writes in `Windows Event Log` localized human readable message and it is very difficult to parse it and find what happens and which drive has crashed.

Comment: Irrelevant. You primarily want to know SOMETHING happened, so you can check ;) the rest is "icing on the cake". Knowing you need to check, first, is most important ;)

Comment: The Event Log also has machine-parsable error codes and whatnot storesd in XML that can be ready by an NMS very easilly